# Indian independence day greetings

Tags: india, local-customs, public-holidays

What's the proper greeting for the Indian independance day? This question is motivated by the fact that we have "happy new years", "merry christmas", and "meaningful thanksgivings".

Answer (score 3):

Many [Bollywood celebrities have taken to twitter](http://www.indianexpress.com/news/shah-rukh-khan-and-other-bollywood-celebs-wish-happy-independence-day/1155849/) to celebrate the occasion, and for the most part they're simply saying "Happy Independence Day".

However, some are including the phrase "Jai_Hind" or "Jai Hind Vande Mataram".

"[Jai Hind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jai_Hind)" often translates to "Long live India", while "Vande Matarm" is roughly "[Hail to the mother(land)](http://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20060828200721AAJCKlr)" or "one mother" (literally ["I bow to thee, mother"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vande_Mataram)), and is the title of the national song (different from the anthem).

However, in recent times this second part is [considered by some to be controversial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vande_Mataram#Public_response).